# Number of outputs in dense softmax layer

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, multiclass-classification

I've been working through a Coursera course for extra practice and ran into an issue I don't understand.
[Link to Collab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/TensorFlow%20In%20Practice/Course%203%20-%20NLP/Course%203%20-%20Week%202%20-%20Exercise%20-%20Answer.ipynb)

So as far as I've worked on ML neural network problems, I've always been taught that the output layer of a multiclass classification problem will be Dense, with number of nodes equal to the number of classes. E.g. Dog, cat, horse - 3 classes = 3 nodes.

However, in the notebook, there are 5 classes in the labels, checked using `len(label_tokenizer.word_index)` but using 5 nodes I had terrible results and with 6 nodes the model worked properly.

Can anyone please explain why this is the case? I can't find any online example explaining this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The output of the dense layer with loss of categorical cross entropy expects labels/targets to be starting from zero. For example:

```
cat - 0
dog - 1
horse - 2
```

In this case, the number of dense nodes are 3.
However, in the collab, the labels were generated using keras tokenizer, which tokenizes starting from 1 (because padding is usually 0).

```
label_tokenizer = Tokenizer()
label_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(labels)
# {'business': 2, 'entertainment': 5, 'politics': 3, 'sport': 1, 'tech': 4}
```

This leads to a weird case where, if we have 5 dense nodes, we have output classes from 0-4, which doesn't match up with our labels with predictions 1-5.

I proved this empirically by rerunning the code with all labels reduced by 1 and the model trains successfully with 5 dense nodes, since labels are 0-4 now.

I suspect that with labels 1-5 and 6 dense nodes work because the model simply learns that label 0 is not used and focuses on 1-5.

If anyone understands the inner workings of categorical cross entropy, do feel free to add on!